# Prove that $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

Tags: field-theory

I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

Suposse that $\sqrt{3}=a+b\sqrt{2}$

$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{3}&=a+b\sqrt{2}\\
3&=(a+b\sqrt{2})^2\\
3&=a^2+2\sqrt{2}ab+b^2\\
(3-a^2-12b^2)^2&=(2\sqrt{2}ab)^2\\
9-6a^2-12b^2+4a^2b^2+a^4+4b^4&=8a^2b^2
\end{align*}$

But I don't know what else I can do here.

Comment: By squaring both sides of $\sqrt{3}-b\sqrt{2}=a$ it is simple to check that $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ implies $\sqrt{6}\in\mathbb{Q}$, that we know to be false.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: Would it not also suffice to explain that the $\sqrt {3} - b \sqrt {2} $ is irrational, so $a $ must be irrational?

Comment: @infinitylord: it is the same thing under a different point of view, I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually continue from your third line by using that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational so if $$a^2+b^2+2\sqrt 2ab=3,$$ then actually $$a^2+b^2=3 \text{ 
 and } 2\sqrt 2ab=0$$ so that either $a$ is zero or $b$ is $0$. Since we can't solve $a^2=3$ or $b^2=3$ in the rationals, you can conclude by using that $\sqrt 3$ is irrational .

Answer (score 1):

At your step
$$3=a^2+2\sqrt 2 ab +2b^2$$, you can rearrange it to be
$$3-a^2-2b^2=2\sqrt 2 ab$$, the left hand side is a rational number while the right hand side is irrational, which you can't do unless a and b are zero, which does not satisfy the first condition.

Comment: @Hurkyl how so?

Comment: I addressed that when I said that when a and b are zero, it doesn't satisfy that root 3 is a plus b root 2

Comment: I missed your addendum where you accounted for my observation. (that $a=0$ or that $b=0$, although you misstated the case as $a=b=0$)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}).$

Hence from

$$3=a^2+b^2+2\sqrt{2}ab$$

We have $a^2+b^2=3$ and $2ab=0$.

From there, you should be able to see a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I would start the same:

$$\sqrt3 = a + b\sqrt{2},\ \ a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$$

then square both to get

$$3 = a^2 + 2ab\sqrt2 + b^2$$

just like you and then rearrange to get

$$\frac{3 - a^2 - b^2}{2ab} = \sqrt{2}$$

meaning that $\sqrt2$ would have to be rational, which we know is not true.

Comment: The contradiction implies at least one of the hypotheses is false -- it could still be the case that $\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and it is the implicit hypothesis of your argument (the assumption that $2ab \neq 0$) that fails!